# renv and git: what to commit

Tags: r, git, renv

I am trying to get me and my colleagues started on using renv. I have found different pieces of information of what should/can be committed to git for collaboration:

1. the [renv collaboration vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/collaborating.html) suggests to not only commit the `renv.lock`, but also the `.RProfile` and `renv/activate.R`
2. it is however [possible](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-is-it-sufficient-to-just-commit-renv-lock/98307) to only commit `renv.lock`

Apparently there was also some [discussion](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/74) from the developers on which strategy to use.

In general (and coming from pyhton, where basically a `requirements.txt` is sufficient), I quite like approach 2. Are there any drawbacks to it? Any changes in what the collaborator then has to do (e.g. start with `renv::restore` or with `renv::init`)?

Comment: "*…coming from pyhton, where basically a `requirements.txt` is sufficient…*" Not exactly true, sorry. `requirements.txt` should contain the result of `pip freeze`, i.e. the full list of packages with dependencies and exact versions. While `requirements.in` should contain only top-level packages with inexact versions or ranges. `requirements.in` is usually created by hand and `requirements.txt`is generated automatically. Plus `Pipfile` plus `Pipfile.lock`. Oops…

Comment: In addition to the comment by @phd, `requirements.txt` is really a minimum effort and is generally *completely insufficient* to generate an isolated environment. Python has other ways for this (some of which do this a lot better than R + ‘renv’) but `requirements.txt` isn’t it.

Comment: fair, my comparison to `requirements.txt` wasn't the best one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The drawback to only committing `renv.lock` is that ‘renv’ won’t be activated automatically when the project is loaded in the usual way, which means that collaborators might accidentally be running code from the project outside the confines of the environment.

Whether this is a problem mainly depends on your internal processes, i.e. how the project will be used. Having some kind of “enforcement” by automatically loading ‘renv’ can definitely be useful, and has essentially no drawbacks — so why not just commit the additional two files?

On the other hand, it should be noted that committing the `.Rprofile` and `renv/activate.R` files *also* doesn’t guarantee that these will be loaded every time the project is loaded. There are unfortunately many scenarios in which R code is executed without automatically sourcing the `.Rprofile` file associated with a project directory (in fact, it’s *only* sourced under very specific circumstances; namely, when the current working directory is set to the project directory). But it’s still better than nothing.

In sum, I don’t see a good reason not to commit all these files if you commit `renv.lock`.